# Dirac Notation With Comma

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, notation, tensor-calculus, quantum-states

Does $\langle A,B\rvert$ mean $\langle A\rvert\langle B\rvert$?

If so how is an operator applied to this in  $\langle A,B\rvert \hat O $? For an example say the annihilation operator acting on $\langle N,0\rvert\hat a$?

Comment: IMHO this is rather broad. Tensor products should be discussed in any introduction to QM. Maybe you should grab a book and read the relevant section.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on conventions of the author, usually yes, though, $\langle A,B|=\langle A|\langle B|=\langle A|\otimes\langle B|$.

If $|A\rangle$ is from $\mathcal{H}_1$ and $|B\rangle$ is from $\mathcal{H}_2$, then an operator that acts on $|A\rangle\otimes|B\rangle$ is a linear operator on $\mathcal{H}_1\otimes\mathcal{H}_2$, however if you have an operator, say $\hat{O}$ that acts on say $\mathcal{H}_1$, then you can extend it into an operator $\hat{O}\otimes\mathrm{Id}_2$, where $\mathrm{Id}_2$ is the identity map on the second Hilbert-space.

The tensor product of operators act as as if $\hat{O}$ acts on $\mathcal{H}_1$, and $\hat{P}$ acts on $\mathcal{H}_2$, then $\hat{O}\otimes\hat{P}(|A\rangle\otimes|B\rangle)=\hat{O}|A\rangle\otimes\hat{P}|B\rangle$, for tensors that are not products, extend linearly.